# Specifying Different Column as DOC ID using Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using the great **Thinking Sphinx** plugin for accessing Sphinx Search in RoR 2.2.3. I have a cache table that stores pre-compiled views. This is the source data table for Sphinx.

However, the ID column on this table is basically garbage, and the ID that I want is stored  in another column (cacheable_id). How can I setup Thinking Sphinx to use the "other column" as Sphinx's DOC ID instead of the plain old "ID" column.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this with Thinking Sphinx at the moment. However, there is [a fork out there](http://github.com/jchupp/thinking-sphinx/tree/alt_primary_key) that does what you need. I'd recommend you create your own fork, and mix the latest official TS release with [the relevant patch](http://github.com/semanticart/thinking-sphinx/commit/67deb3b0194f895fa4948ac8a897aaf1b1751213) from this fork. I'm not quite sure how cleanly it will merge though.

Comment: Thanks Pat, i restructured things so it would work with your plugin out of the box. No point making things too complex. Cheers!

Comment: FWIW, Pat has now merged the fork into the latest thinking sphinx